# Django Rest Framework Serializer charfield not updating when source is given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model field with choices charfield

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("N", "New"),
        ("U", "Used"),
        ("P", "Just Purchased")
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

The serializer class also has charfield for status but with `source` argument to display the readable value

```
class VehicleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.CharField(source='get_status_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
```

When I try to update vehicles through patch request with data `{'status': "U"}`, there is no update performed.
However the update occurs when I remove the `source` from serializer status field.
Providing source is necessary to display proper value in web view.

I know the option of changing the name of status in serializer to something other and using that in the template. Also there is the option to override update method in serializer, however my question is what is source doing to prevent the update?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add status to the fields list in meta.

```
class VehicleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     status = serializers.CharField(source='get_status_display')

     class Meta:
         model = Vehicle
         fields = ('status',)
```

Comment: status is added by default as it has same name that of the field in model.