# DRF Updating model's CharFiled with choices doesn't do anything

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Task` app in my django project.

So this is the base class for the task model:

```py
TASK_STATUSES = [
    ("DN", "Done"),
    ("IP", "In progress"),
    ("IR", "In review"),
    ("NW", "New"),
    ("RJ", "Rejected"),
    ("TD", "To do"),
]

class TaskBase(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = TASK_STATUSES

    status = models.CharField("State", max_length=2, default="NW", choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    [...]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This is the actual model:

```py
class Task(TaskBase):
    TYPE_CHOICES = TASK_TYPES

    type = models.CharField("Type", max_length=1, default="T", choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.CharField(source="get_status_display")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

And the viewset:

```py
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    lookup_field = "name"
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []
```

Now I update the task's status via `PATCH` request to `/api/task/<task_name>/` with `{"status": "TD"}`.

So the response is `"PATCH /api/task/XYZ/ HTTP/1.1" 200 233` - everything is fine, I receive `"TD"` in the response data - the status changed. But when I get the task again, it still has his previous status ("New").

So I see two problems:

- I change the status, 200 HTTP response, the response from api contains changed status - **but it does not change in my DB**
- The status that I receive in response is not in "To do" format, it's TD

No matter what I put, `"TD"` or `"To do"`, the response is 200 and the status is not actually being changed. The thing is, when I remove the `status` field from the serializer - the changes are actually being done! But then, I lose the display feature (getting e.g. "New" instead of "NW" from the API) even in GET requests. Even so, I am pretty sure that i should get the display name in both get/update requests.

Anyway, I even tried doing `status = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Task.STATUS_CHOICES)` and it works the same way. When I add `source="get_status_display"` here, it starts to behave the same way as with `CharField` - doesn't actually update.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want here - both get and update type response return `status` as its display name + the changes made via `PATCH` requests are actually being done?

@Edit

I guess it's the same as in here: [Django Rest Framework Serializer charfield not updating when source is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449610/django-rest-framework-serializer-charfield-not-updating-when-source-is-given) - unanswered

Comment: What is the sample payload that you were used while PATCHing?

Comment: `{"status": "TD"}`, or `{"status": "To do"}` - the same result. Actually, I can even put `FooBarBaz123456` there - the response is still 200, I still get this (`FooBarBaz123456`) in the response data and the data is not being changed

Comment: And when I use the `ChoiceField`, I cannot pass random data and I cannot pass something like `To do`, it has to be the short version - **but** still when I pass the correct one (like `TD`) the change is not being made (when I use `source=`, when I don't , it's fine). So the problem here, no matter which field type I choose is using `source=`

Comment: *"it has to be the short version"*, Yeah, it should be

Comment: Yes, so okay, I use the short version, but still, when I add `source=` to my field (which I want to have), the changes are not being made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're overriding the name of real database field with a property of the model.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    long_status_name = serializers.CharField(source="get_status_display")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

This will allow you to update "status" now with no problems, and return an additional field called "long_status_name" with the full text of the status.

Comment: Yes, I know. The thing is, this is not the answer 4 me. Why do I have to define this additional field just to satisfy write actions. The thing I did is I created two separate serializers and I use them based on the request action type. The read serializer is used for gets/lists, write serializer for other actions. And then, the read serializer contains fields with `source` and the write serializer doesn't override anything. The result is - data is being changed, proper displays (like `"New"`) are being returned from the API. I had to override `update` and `create` methods in my viewset.

Comment: It's quite unusual from a REST/api perspective to pollute fields like this. In one context you're saying you accept on the code, and in another context it's the value. All APIs are different and we're free to do as we like, but personally I prefer to have explicit fields for the display .vs. storage.

Comment: I understand. Then I wonder why the `source=` kwarg got introduced if this is a bad practice

Comment: it's not bad practice to use the source field - you often use these fields to stop clashes or allow non-breaking changes to be introduced; say introducing a field name change, but wanting to keep the existing "field name" in your API.

Comment: But then using the source field just to get the field's representation in GET request - bad practice or not?

Comment: It's bad practice because you're not aliasing a field, you're changing the meaning of the field. Insomuch as, when the user is "writing" their code has to be aware of codes, but when reading they code has to handle display text. Say the choices for example are dynamic, generally someone would change the display name, but not necessarily the underlying code associated - under your approach, the end-system has to be aware of both codes and text. Does that make sense?